# ROS Answers SE migration: roswtf error

Tags: ros, ros-package-path, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello!

when i run `roswtf` based on [the tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Getting%20started%20with%20roswtf), i am getting following error, How to fix it? I am using rosws (http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) for managing workspace.

Thanks

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 2 error(s).

ERROR Not all paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH [/home/ahmad/ROSworksapce/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros] point to an existing directory: 
 * /home/ahmad/ROSworksapce/sandbox

ERROR Not all paths in PYTHONPATH [/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages:] point to a directory: 
 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/roslib/src

================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://localhost:11311]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41808/roswtf-error/) by [ama](https://answers.ros.org/users/3049/ama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-08-19

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All in all, there isn't anything here to be concerned about. You can probably ignore these errors.

> No package or stack in context

This is just telling you that the current working directory from which you're calling roswtf is neither a ros stack or a ros package.

> ERROR Not all paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
> [/home/ahmad/ROSworksapce/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros]
> point to an existing directory: *
> /home/ahmad/ROSworksapce/sandbox

This is telling you that some directories in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH don't exist. Specifically, "/home/ahmad/ROSworksapce/sandbox" doesn't exist. Check the .rosinstall file in your ros workspace and remove it if you don't want to see this message.

> ERROR Not all paths in PYTHONPATH
> [/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages:]
> point to a directory: *
> /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/roslib/src

This is telling you that some directories in your PYTHONPATH don't exist. Specifically, "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/roslib/src" doesn't exist. This looks like it's a (benign) bug in the PYTHONPATH exported by setup.sh. It used to be that that was where roslib lived, but not anymore. This might warrant a ticket if one doesn't already exist.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-09-16**:\

> No package or stack in context

I found this msg is unclear as well, so opened [ros/ros_comm#1505](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1505).

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-04-27**:
@jbohren seems that nobody open a ticket for the issue with the PYTHONPATH. I get this message too, if I run `roswtf`